# js regex to capture last word before first comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
const str = "bbb=12m3 3be3 34f4, foo=2344 234234 dqda, baz=asdasd asdasd"
const match = str.match(Need the correct regex here);
console.log(match[match.length-1]);
```

I would like to extract whatever the last 'word' is before the first comma.  In the example above it would be 34f4.

I tried `/bbb=(.*?),/`  which gave me 12m3 3be3 34f4

I tried `/bbb=(.+\s(.*)?),/`  which gave me dqda

I feel I'm kinda close but can't quite get it.

Edit - I need to specifically look for the string 'bbb' as other strings may be tested that do not have it, or bbb may be in a different order within the string

ex. I may get

```
const str = "zzz=12m3 3be3 34f4, foo=2344 234234 dqda, baz=asdasd asdasd"
```

which would return nothing

Or I may get

```
const str = "foo=2344 234234 dqda, bbb=12m3 3be3 34f4, baz=asdasd asdasd"
```

where the bbb is in a different location

Comment: I have adjusted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876761/11299053) to pass all of the test cases you mentioned above. Does it work now as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/bbb=[^,]*\s([^,\s]*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YhNBz/1)

**Details**

- `bbb=` - a `bbb=` substring
- `[^,]*` - 0 or more chars other than `,` as many as possible
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `([^,\s]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than a comma and whitespace

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['bbb=12m3 3be3 34f4, foo=2344 234234 dqda, baz=asdasd asdasd','zzz=12m3 3be3 34f4, foo=2344 234234 dqda, baz=asdasd asdasd','foo=2344 234234 dqda, bbb=12m3 3be3 34f4, baz=asdasd asdasd'];
var regex = /bbb=[^,]*\s([^,\s]*)/;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  var m = strs[i].match(regex);
  console.log(strs[i], "=>", ( m ? m[1] : "None!"));
}
```

Comment: Looks great here but seems to barf on my end, pointing at the dot in ?.[1] saying expected an operand but found .

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 It is called ["optional chaining"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and can be expressed in many other ways. What is your browser?

Comment: It's not in a browser, but in a server called Vert.x

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 Revamped code to be ES5 compatible, in case you need to run it in IE.

Comment: I see in the link you sent me that NodeJs is not supported, so Vert.x likely is the same

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 I have changed the demo code. It is not relevant. The regex stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) once to get only the first match:

```js
console.log(/([^\s,]+),/.exec("bbb=12m3 3be3 34f4, foo=2344 234234 dqda, baz=asdasd asdasd"))
```

The return values is an array. First element is the whole match, second element the first capture group.

Comment: Looks good but I need the bbb part. I edited the OP to mention that better

Comment: You could always have a second regex that just tests whether the string starts with this sequence. E.g. `/^bbb=/.test(str) && /.../.exec(str)`.